# MySQL ORDER BY FIELD with %

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I am trying to make an ORDER BY FIELD work with a wildcard, and have been unsuccessful:

```
SELECT positions.*, 
       departments.dept_name, 
       departments.dept_url, 
       divisions.dept_name AS div_name
FROM positions LEFT JOIN departments 
           ON positions.colleague_dept_code = departments.colleague_code 
     LEFT JOIN departments AS divisions 
          ON positions.colleague_div_code = divisions.colleague_code
WHERE colleague_id = '$colleague_id'
ORDER BY FIELD(positions.colleague_position_id, 'A%', 'F%', 'T%', 'S%', 'C%')
```

The `colleague_position_id` field has a text ID generated by our MIS system, and I'd like for positions starting with A to display first, F to display second, etc., etc.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a separate table for your positions and have a 'rank' column as well? Then you can join with your existing query and order by positrion.rank.

Comment: No, because unfortunately, each position ID is different, and the only way for us to determine rank is based on the letter. There's nothing numerical tying them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the most control over it:

```
order by
  case left(positions.colleague_position_id, 1)
    when 'A' then 1
    when 'F' then 2
    when 'T' then 3
    when 'S' then 4
    when 'C' then 5
    else 6
  end, positions.colleague_position_id
```

This is because you can send all non-matching values to the position you want (in this case at the end). The `field()` function will return `0` for non matching values and will put them at the top of the result set even before the ones starting with `A`.

Additionally, you can also order by `positions.colleague_position_id` as I did in the example, so that for many `positions.colleague_position_id` that start with the same letter they will still be in order.

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the `WildCard`?

> ORDER BY FIELD(positions.colleague_position_id, 'A', 'F', 'T', 'S', 'C')

[See Source: ORDER BY SPECIFIC VALUE](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)